# More elegant way to get the next meeting date

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Is there a more elegant way to do what I'm trying to do below? Get the date of the next meeting using linq.

In Model ODM has NextMeeting property (GET) that will be displayed on a display.

[EDITED]

Possibilities of errors:

There's no Meetings in OdmMeetiings (empty).

There's no Meetings in OdmMeetiings with date > today.

(I translate all code names To english to help understand, if you found somethin wrong you can edit)

```
namespace Models
{
    public partial class ODM
    {
        public ODM()
        {
             this.OdmMeetiings = new List<OdmMeeting>();
        }

        public int Id  { get;  set; }


        public String NextMeeting //There is a more elegant way to do this. 
        {
            get
            {
                var OdmReuniao = this.OdmMeetiings
                    .Where(x => x.Meeting != null && x.Meeting.StartDate > DateTime.Now)
                    .Select(x => x.Meeting)
                    .ToList() //If is possible, without use ToList
                    .Min(x => x.StartDate)
                    ;


                return OdmReuniao.ToShortDateString();
            }
        }

        public virtual ICollection<OdmMeeting> OdmMeetiings { get; set; }

        }
}

namespace Models
{
    public partial class OdmMeeting
    {
        public int IdMeeting { get; set; }
        public int IdODM { get; set; }
        public virtual ODM ODM { get; set; }
        public virtual Meeting Meeting { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Models
{
    public partial class Meeting
    {
        public Meeting()
        {
            this.ODMs = new List<OdmMeeting>();
        }

        public int Id { get;  set; }

        public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<OdmMeeting> ODMs { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: `.FirstOrDefault()`?

Comment: They just tell me now that if there is no meeting, I have to show a "-". That is, the return will be a string. I will edit the code.

Comment: I've updated my answer to consider these possibilities after @DerekVanCuyk's comment about OrderBy throwing an exception

Comment: Was there some reason you had to use .ToList in this code?

Comment: Jakotheshadows - No reason, just test, it can be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

First, you need to test whether `Meetings` have items. The `this.OdmMeetiings.Count` property shows this.

Second: You need to test the `StartDate > DateTime.Now` condition to know whether to return at least one item (if you want to skip the time, use the Date property).

Third: Not need to order to get the next date, `Min` already does this.

The code below:

```
    public string NextMeeting
    {
        get
        {
            return this.OdmMeetiings.Count > 0 
                    && this.OdmMeetiings.Any(x => x.Meeting.StartDate.Date > DateTime.Now.Date) ?
                    this.OdmMeetiings.Where(x => x.Meeting.StartDate.Date > DateTime.Now.Date).Min(x => x.Meeting.StartDate).ToShortDateString() 
                    : "-"; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should have used `Any` instead of `Count` to check if Meetings has any items.  That would then make it redundant as any case in which this.OdmMeetiings has any meetings with a start date > now, implicitly has some Meetings.

Comment: Robert McKee - You mean I should remove .Count, because .any (StartDate> Now) already checks for items?
But when the ".any" run "x.Meeting.StartDate" will not throw an exception if OdmMeetiings is empty? (OdmMeetiings.Count == 0 -> x.Meeting not exist)

Comment: Actually, the .Any call should be doing null checking. Count > 0 is redundant with .Any, as Robert McKee said, and could be removed with the same effect but the .Any call needs to make sure OdmMeeting.Meeting isn't null like this:

this.OdmMeetiings.Any(x => x.Meeting != null && x. blah blah blah ...

Answer (score 2):

Rather than calling the ToList you can order by the query and then get the first element.

```
var OdmReuniao = this.OdmMeetiings
.Where(x => x.Meeting != null && x.Meeting.StartDate > DateTime.Now)
.Select(x => x.Meeting)
.OrderBy(x => x.Meeting.StartDate)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

obviously you can order the date as per your requirement.

`FirstOrDefault()` will return the first element or the default for the type (generally a null).

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: updated to account for possibility that collection may be empty and possibility that there may be no OdmMeeting(s) with non null Meeting references. Updated to filter out null meeting references before sorting.

```
OdmMeeting odmMeeting = this.OdmMeetiings
                    .Where(x => x.Meeting != null)
                    .OrderBy(x => x.Meeting.StartDate)
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Meeting.StartDate > DateTime.Now);

return odmMeeting != null ? odmMeeting.Meeting.StartDate.ToShortDateString() : "-";
```

Also since you're just after 1 element, and don't really need to reformat the output of an entire collection Select() seems like overkill.

Comment: The StartDate is a non nullable property. If there is no Meeting, will not throw an exception?

Comment: He is filtering out any meetings that are null in the FIrst method.

Comment: It was I who put the filter, (the question). If the filter is true, Meeting == null, then Meeting.StarDate will throw an exception. Another question I have, is that OdmMeetiings is a collection that can come empty, then x.Meeting could throw an exception? Therefore wanted a better way to do the query considering all this without giving error.

Comment: Updated the answer to account for those possibilities.

Comment: @Elizeu You're correct. The OrderBy will throw an exception if there is x.Meeting == null